# PHP Image upload crop error

Tags: php, upload, crop

i'm trying to use an upload/crop php script for an image upload form I want on a website.  It uses ImageManipulator.php for anyone who's heard of it and the upload works fine but the actual trim/crop and add to folder are not working.  Here is my code:

```
//Avatar Preferences
$avatar = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["avatar"]);
// include ImageManipulator class
require_once('../scripts/ImageManipulator.php');

if ($_FILES[$avatar]['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES[$avatar]['error'] . "<br />";
} else {
    // array of valid extensions
    $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
    // get extension of the uploaded file
    $fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES[$avatar]['name'], ".");
    // check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
    if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
        $newNamePrefix = time() . '_';
        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES[$avatar]['tmp_name'])or die(mysqli_error());
        $width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
        $height = $manipulator->getHeight();
        $centreX = round($width / 2);
        $centreY = round($height / 2);
        // our dimensions will be 200x130
        $x1 = $centreX - 100; // 200 / 2
        $y1 = $centreY - 65; // 130 / 2

        $x2 = $centreX + 100; // 200 / 2
        $y2 = $centreY + 65; // 130 / 2

        // center cropping to 200x130
        $newImage = $manipulator->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
        // saving file to uploads folder
        $manipulator->save('../uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES[$avatar]['name']);
        echo 'Done ...';
    } else {
        echo 'You must upload an image...';
    }
}
```

Do any of you see a potential problem here?  Thank you

Comment: @Jocelyn, code which doesn't work is off-topic over on Code Review. Please don't suggest that people send it there.

Comment: What is the output? Does it work if you take out the cropping? What happens if you remove the extension check? What is this ImageManipulator from? What happens if you hard-code the target path? (Basically, can you remove parts of this code and still see the problem? If so, do that.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @WinstonEwert - I'm using JQuery.form for the actual upload and I've found out that it doesn't work in Firefox 19.0.2 which I'm running testing on - I tried it on Chrome, Safari and Opera and both the upload and crop/re-size work fine

Comment: now that's odd. How about `print_r`ing the $_FILES array from both browsers to see what's different?

Comment: I could but it's actually a known error on Firefox as explained here https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/304 - Hoping it's only a temporary problem

Comment: Someone has reported a problem, but it was closed. It's not really been accepted as a known issue...